# Using FileUploadField extension with extjs3.4

Tags: javascript, file-upload, extjs

Trying to handle with the FileUploadField extension for ExtJS 3.4 provided on Examples web page (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/form/file-upload.html), **I can't get any of the tree examples to be as it is shown on web page**. And of course, can't get them work as they might.

When I specify a "FileUpLoadField" on my application, there appear two "browse.." buttons: It seems that one belongs to the ExtJS extension and another belongs to the browser. 
On the other hand appear what it seems to be two textfields and there's no Icon.

I've got the FileUpLoadField" extension copying code that's provided on: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/ux/fileuploadfield/FileUploadField.js

I've put this code on a .js file and added it as a library on my app.

I suppose this issue is related with browser/ExtJS extension I'm using.

**Could anyone try to explain what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: can you create your example on http://jsfiddle.net/EugeneDae/hWGYE/

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't add link to FileUploadField.css in your code.